# How to get userid on visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I am using this query on apex:

```
  @RemoteAction
    public static string GetUserEmail(string userid)
    {    
    String usrid = UserInfo.getUserId() ;
    string queryString= 'select Id,name,Email from User where id=:usrid';
           return queryString;

    }
```

But now I do not know how to get this id on visualpage.

Comment: what do you want on VF page? current user details ?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on exactly what you are trying to do you might need not any code (it's unclear why you using a remote action), you could use the Global Variable `$User`:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm

For example:

```
<apex:page>
  <h1>User Info Page</h1>
   This is your new Apex Page
   <p>UserId: {!$User.Id}</p>
   <p>User Email: {!$User.Email}</p>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [$User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm) Global variable to get the details of the current logged in user in your Visualforce page.

To get the Id use `{!$User.Id}`

Hope it helps.

Comment: No it is give me id but m using knocout js here when i got userid than on this id base i got only this user email